# CURL: how to run a single curl command 3 times if it fails with error and condition is not met?

Tags: shell, loops, curl

I'm running a curl command inside a loop, I want that if my curl command fails, it should re-run that loop including curl command 3 times .What should be right approach of doing that?

```
while [[ "$Environment" == "Dev" ]];

do

curl command

done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write separate function as below and use:

```
#!/bin/sh

count=0
execute_curl () {
   count=`expr $count + 1`
   curl command
   if [ $? -ne 0 ] && [ $count -lt 3 ]
   then
      execute_curl
   else
      return $?
   fi
}

while [[ "$Environment" == "Dev" ]];
do
execute_curl
done
```